# OpenLayers 3 / Geoserver - add popup w/ attributes to Image layer?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, layers, fields-attributes, popup

I have a web app using OpenLayers 3, with several layers added as image layers, like so:

```
 mylayer= new ol.layer.Image({
     source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
         url: 'http://server/geoserver/opengeo/wms',
         params: { 'LAYERS': 'layername' },
         serverType: 'geoserver'
     })
 });
```

I would like to have an info window popup on the click of a feature , I am following the example here : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.1/examples/icon.html

I have Bootstrap and JQuery in my app (these are both needed for this example) and am not getting any errors, but no results either..

..this example is for a vector layer, and so far I haven't been able to get this to work for me...Is there a way I can do this with an image layer? or do I need to add the layer as a vector layer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43695/discussion-on-question-by-jasonbk-openlayers-3-geoserver-add-popup-w-attrib).

Comment: @iant since you have been very unhelpful, I don't wish to chat - I would prefer you remove the 'duplicate' flag and let someone else edit this post, thanks.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question

Comment: @JasonBK try the answer on the question that iant marked yours as a duplicate of it, if it doesn't work then post the error or the problem as an edit

Comment: @HichamZouarhi as I said in the comments that Iant deleted, the link I posted in my initial question, which I tried, gives essentially the same method for retrieving features as the supposed duplicate answer posted above..there were no errors, and no features returned.  I also mentioned this in my initial question.

Comment: @JasonBK I don't think that it's doable using WMS since it displays the features as an image, you probably should use WFS instead

Comment: @HichamZouarhi yes, I mention this possibility in my question as well, which is again, as I said in the  comments deleted by iant, why this is NOT the same question as the 'duplicate' question posted above

Comment: @iant I posted the answer above..as I said, the duplicate answer you posted does not work in this case, and I had already tried that, as I noted in my original question.

Comment: @HichamZouarhi - it is doable, see my answer posted above

Comment: @JasonBK thanks for the answer, upvoted it so that hopefully a moderator will notice it

Comment: @JasonBK  this is still a duplicate!  please post your answer the linked answer so that others will see it and be able to give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already tried the method given in the 'duplicate' answer, which works for vector layers but not image layers.  I also noted this in the link posted in my original question, which the editor apparently did not read.

This solution uses a Bootstrap popup - - it is based on code from [this example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html)

```
var element = document.getElementById('popup');

var popup = new ol.Overlay({
    element: element,
    positioning: 'bottom-center',
    stopEvent: false
});
map.addOverlay(popup);

var wmsSource = window.globals.map.getLayers().getArray()[5].getSource();
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = 10; ///** @type {number} */ (mapView.getResolution());
    var url = wmsSource.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution, 'EPSG:3857',
        { 'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html' });
    if (url) {

                popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
                $(element).popover({
                    'placement': 'top',
                    'html': true,
                    'content': '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>'

                });

                $(element).popover('show');
                 $(element).css('display', 'block');

    }
```